# How to load a secret.properties file in apacheignite/docker stock image

Tags: spring, docker, ignite

I used gridgain’s webconsole to create a configuration file for my ignite node (ignite-config.xml).  I’d like to see if I can get this running in apache’s docker ignite image (apacheignite/ignite).  I’ve created a volume in my compose file that maps to a config folder that houses my ignite-config.xml.

I need to include the secret.properties (that has my jdbc url/username/password) file as well so I put it in the config folder too.

When I do a docker-compose up I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/secret.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist]`

This is the part of the xml config that deals with the secret.properties location:

```
   <!-- Load external properties file. -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:secret.properties"/>
    </bean>
```

What do I need to change so that the secret.properties file in the config folder is loaded?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you open a shell inside the container can you find secret.properties at the right location?

Comment: When I bash into the docker container the 2 files (ignite-config.xml and secret.properties) are in the ./config folder.  I suspect I need to change the xml location but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If I look at the official page (https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.5/docs/docker-deployment) you should only pass the path to the xml document and it will be automatically saved in the right location. See the parameter CONFIG_URI, especially the part where it says relative to the META-INF

Comment: I am only passing the xml document (config file).  However inside of the config file there is a reference to a 'secret.properties' file.  I need a way to pass in the database information into the instance.

Comment: Have you tried specifying absolute path to secret.properties in location property? I guess it will always be the same with Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to easily deploy the secret.properties file without going through a full build and deploy, but in order to get past that for testing purposes, you could get rid of the secret.properties and use environment variables instead.

Which might look something like this for a JDBC connection to Postgres:

```
<!-- Data source beans will be initialized from external properties file. -->
<bean id="dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="#{systemEnvironment['dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_url']}"/>
    <property name="user" value="#{systemEnvironment['dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_username']}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{systemEnvironment['dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_password']}"/>
</bean>
```

Then, just set your environment variables:

```
IGNITE_VERSION=2.7.5
CONFIG_URI=https://raw.github.com/some/path/to/your/config.xml
OPTION_LIBS=ignite-zookeeper,ignite-rest-http
EXTERNAL_LIBS=https://github.com/some/path/to/your/jdbc-drivers/postgresql-42.2.6.jar?raw=true
dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_username=0a9suf09asdfkjwel
dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_password=8faskdfn94noiasnf09_s09fklajfealk
dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc_url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/Daifcqkp30zkdj?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, probably didn't resolve it the "correct" way (whatever that is), but resolved it this way for a POC nonetheless:

1. Create a standalone jar file with only the secrets file
2. Give it the name dsPostgreSQL_Daifcqkp30zkdj_jdbc.jar or similar
3. Place the jar file in the libs directory

It seems the classpath is just the contents of all JAR files in the \libs subdir, so oblige it...  This would have the advantage of allowing for a signed JAR - I believe - which would (in addition to file system permissions, visibility, etc.) at least ensure it isn't tampered with.